# Repacking TIFF using LibTiff.Net in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, tiff, libtiff.net

All I need is to take TIFF file, open it and copy to new file while using G4 compression.

So, I took LibTiff.Net and TiffCP utility. Did my best to convert code from TIffCP and here is function I have:

```
public static byte[] ConvertToG4Tiff(byte[] input)
{
    var c = new Copier();

    // Set compression to g4
    if (!c.ProcessCompressOptions("g4")) return null;

    // Open output tiff
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var tiffStream = new TiffStream();
    using (var outImage = Tiff.ClientOpen(string.Empty, "w", memoryStream, tiffStream))
    {
        using (var inImage = Tiff.ClientOpen(string.Empty, "read", new MemoryStream(input), new TiffStream()))
        {
            if (inImage == null) return null;

            int totalPages = inImage.NumberOfDirectories();
            for (var i = 0; i < totalPages;)
            {
                c.m_config = PlanarConfig.UNKNOWN;
                c.m_compression = c.m_defcompression;
                c.m_predictor = c.m_defpredictor;
                c.m_fillorder = 0;
                c.m_rowsperstrip = 0;
                c.m_tilewidth = -1;
                c.m_tilelength = -1;
                c.m_g3opts = c.m_defg3opts;

                if (!inImage.SetDirectory((short)i)) return null;
                if (!c.Copy(inImage, outImage) || !outImage.WriteDirectory()) return null;

                i++;
            }
        }

        var retVal = new byte[tiffStream.Size(memoryStream)];
        tiffStream.Read(memoryStream, retVal, 0, retVal.Length);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I think last 3 lines is where I messed up. I do get valid byte array back (There is data and it's about 10% of original uncompressed TIFF)

When I try to open it with code again - it won't open. Passing this new array through this same function will not work. Opened object is NULL.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use `memoryStream` to retrieve compressed data. Do not use `tiffStream` for anything in a code like this.

So, the

```
var retVal = new byte[tiffStream.Size(memoryStream)];
tiffStream.Read(memoryStream, retVal, 0, retVal.Length);
return retVal;
```

should probably be changed to

```
var retVal = memoryStream.ToArray();
return retVal;
```

Please also note that your code won't *convert* data so if input bytes are not 1bpp raster than the code will fail.

It's unclear why would you want to pass compressed data to the same code.

Comment: Yes, changing code like this works! I was passing compressed data to the same code just to test if I had valid output, this is not in final code.. Thanks for the converting remark. I need to dig more into TIFF specs, but I think it will be fine. I'm working with customer that have huge document base and they all scanned uncompressed... This is what I'm testing with.